# How to get React Context Value outside React world(without consumer or useContext)?

Tags: reactjs, analytics

In Redux, we have `store.getState()`.

How can I do the same thing in React Context without `Consumer` or `useContext`?

I think that it is possible, but I don't know if this against design pattern.

I want to do this thing because my context will fetch my server data, then I want to track some google analytics based on that fetched data.

If I have to create a **function component** just because getting those values, that will be too bad.